# Product Catalog "Import Twice Daily" option

Tags: marketing-cloud, product

I need to populate the product catalog in Marketing Cloud using the FTP integration. I intend to use the "Scheduled Import Time" option, but I fail to understand the relationship between the "Import Twice Daily?" checkbox and the configured time (see image below).

My guess is that the execution will be triggered at the configured time *and again* 12 hours later, but I can't find this in the documentation. Can anybody confirm if this is the behavior?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct, when you check the import twice daily it will happen twice a day 12 hrs apart

Comment: Thanks! do you have a link to the documentation supporting your statement?

Comment: AS you stated there isn't anything in documentation